How can I start a pyspark file in a cluster if is not supported by documentation?
I'm trying to start a pyspark.py file in cluster mode, but I receive this error:
Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters.
So my question is, if pyspark use python, but python is not supported in cluster mode, how can I use spark?
I use --deploy-mode cluster as recommended.
